# Sending UDP Packets from Matlab to Java

Tags: java, matlab, udp, double, arrays

i am trying to send two double values as a UDP Packet from Matlab to a Java program but i m unable to access both of them simultaneously.can anyone suggest to me how this could be achieved.

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class UDPReceive {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      int port = 25001;

      // Create a socket to listen on the port.
      DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

      // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);


      while (true) {

        dsocket.receive(packet);


        String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
        Double x = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getDouble();


        System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "
             +" "+x+" ");

        // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
        packet.setLength(buffer.length);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UDP packets are not 100% successful. There is a fair chance your packet will arrive late or even never. Your issue could be caused by almost anything.

If you want a guaranteed connection, try using TCP. TCP is much more reliable at the cost of speed.